# AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'reset_input_buffer'

Tags: python

Hey guys I have a problem with the command 'rest_input_buffer'.
serial.Serial for example works. I've got the latest version of Thonny 3.3.3, Python 3.7.3 and pyserial version 3.5
The important input:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
serial.reset_input_buffer()
```

This is my output:

```
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'reset_input_buffer'
```

Any ideas? I already uninstall pyserial and installed it again, same with python. I get a similiar error with the former command 'flushInput()'

Comment: Provide the version number of the `pyserial` package that you're using. Usually it should work from version `3.2.1`. Try `pip install --upgrade pyserial`

Comment: Pyserial version 3.5 , The newest one.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a *distribution* called `serial`, which also has module named `serial`. Try `import serial; print(serial.__file__)` to make sure you are importing the right thing.

Comment: @kewa I meant `pyserial` version >= `3.2.1` not `python` version. Did you try `pip install --upgrade pyserial`. And make sure as @Aivar said to remove any other package named `serial` with `pip uninstall serial`.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that.
pi@raspberrypi:$ sudo pip install --upgrade pyserial
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (3.5)
pi@raspberrypi:$ sudo pip uninstall serial
WARNING: Skipping serial as it is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You already start your serial session with:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
```

Try to flush your buffer like this:

```
ser.reset_input_buffer()
```